# Error appears when post value to php by using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I get an error while posting datas to php file. Codes below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: "{'konuid='" + $('#step2-id').val() + "','kategoriid='" +$('#step3-id').val() +"'}",
        success: function(data){
            $('#form-sorular').html(data);
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    });
```

I checked the value in php file which is coming from ajax, and values were empty.. What is wrong with this ajax.

Comment: This would be the correct syntax -> http://jsfiddle.net/NePV2/, and how are you checking this on the serverside.

Comment: $konuid = $_POST['konuid'];
if(empty($konuid)){echo "0";} I check the value with this way

Comment: So the key exists, but has no value. Are you sure the element #step2-id is returning a value.

Comment: http://hizliresim.com/xVJmJr - this is the screenshot of firebug post result.But ajax error part running and alerts "undefined"

Comment: You should not be building your own ajax string. Any JS metacharacters in the `.val()` you're inserting will almost certainly make the entire JSON string be invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a JSON formatted string for the `data` value, but I am guessing your server code is expecting values as if you posted a form. So instead of a string that looks like this:

```
{'konuid='step2-id-val','kategoriid='step3-id-val'}
```

You should pass a string that looks like this:

```
konuid=step2-id-val&kategoriid=step3-id-val
```

But rather than concatenate the string yourself, you should set the `data` value to an object, and then JQuery will format the string for you:

```
data: {
    konuid: $('#step2-id').val(),
    kategoriid: $('#step3-id').val()
},
```

Note: JQuery will properly encode the values when it builds the string.

---

And since your ajax call apparently returns html, I suggest you include the `dataType` setting:

```
dataType: 'html',
```

---

Also, the signature of the error callback is:

```
function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

Change the error setting to:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
    alert('Response: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
}
```